# Polling a web service

Tags: c#, winforms, service, web

I have a C# desktop Windows form application.

Every 3 seconds I am invoking a call to a web service to check for messages in a directory on my server.

I have a `while (true)` loop, which was started by a thread.  Inside this loop the call to the web service is made. I know I should avoid infinite loops, but I do not know an easy way of notifying my client of a new message in a timely fashion.

Are there alternatives I could look at please?

Thanks!

Comment: Infinite loops are fine as long as you have the right conditions in place to break out of it if needed.

Comment: The best way would be that your C# App would be notified by the Web Server when new messages are available. But I don't know how.. Is there anyone wo knows how to do that?

Comment: @DeeMac Hi, thanks for replying. The only way the loop will stop is when the User clicks  a button to exit. If the routine hits an error (like cannot make a connection or connection busy) then it exits the loop and call the whole routine again.  Not sure if that is adequate?

Comment: @Dannydust Hi, thanks for replying. Yes, i had envisaged that this is the best way to go but not sure how..

Comment: @Andrew I am a WinForms Dev too and that would be really nice to know. I am very curious... Thanks for your Question.

Comment: hey we are in this together :). I did look at WCF with the call back but it seems u needed a dedicated binding. With web services it is a bit more dynamic and manageable (IMHO).  I was  going to look a SignalR next. let u know :)

Comment: SignalR is brilliant for what you want here. Definitely worth spending a few hours looking into it. Other than that, you're left with long polling (sort of waiting for the server's response and reacting accordingly in the callback before immediately calling the service again, which almost mimics the concept of 'push').

Comment: Just to give some feedback on this approach... In order for this to work I have to create a server ub. I also cannot use port 80 and my client has to use the same port on the hub. This means i have to make sure the port is open on firewall on my client apps. Whilst doable it is not the way i want to do things :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use a `BackgroundWorker` for this - [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You'd still need to use while(true) loop but you can communicate to the client by use the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress Method:

```
// start the BackgroundWorker somewhere in your code:
DownloadDataWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); //DownloadDataWorker is the BackgroundWorker
```

then write the handlers for `DoWork` and `ProgressChanged`

```
private void DownloadRpdBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (true)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(1);
        if (!controller.DownloadServerData())
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(2);
        }
        else
        {
            //data download succesful
            worker.ReportProgress(3);
        }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //poll every 3 secs
    }
}

private void DownloadRpdBgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.ProgressPercentage){
        case 1: SetStatus("Trying to fetch new data.."); break;
        case 2: SetStatus("Error communicating with the server"); break;
        case 3: SetStatus("Data downloaded!"); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Sorry for misreading. If you want to do something every 3 seconds, Use timers:

```
public static bool Stop = false;

public static void CheckEvery3Sec()
{
   System.Timers.Timer tm = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
   tm.Start();
   tm.Elapsed += delegate
   {
       if (Stop)
       {
          tm.Stop();
          return;
       }
       ...
   };
}
```

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: I honestly cannot work out what you're suggesting here Warlock. Interested to see more context to your approach (not being sarcastic, genuinely interested).