# Autodesk forge viewer gives error after updation of tls1.2

Tags: autodesk-forge

we have uploaded ipt and rvt files into autodesk forge bucket to view files into viewer.

Following segment show how we translate file to view into viewer.html.

Code is executed successfully but, when we open file into viewer, it gives error that file is not viewable.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("contenttype", "application/json");
            string url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job";

            JObject jsonbody = new JObject
                  (
                      new JProperty("input", new JObject
                          (
                              new JProperty("urn", urn)
                          )),
                      new JProperty("output", new JObject
                          (
                              new JProperty("formats", new JArray
                                  (
                                      new JObject
                                              (
                                                  new JProperty("type", "svf"),
                                                  new JProperty("views", new JArray("3d", "2d"))                                             
                                              )
                                  ))
                          ))
                  );

            var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonbody);
            StringContent insertString = new StringContent(ser, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, insertString).Result;
            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JObject jsonobject = JObject.Parse(result);
            urn = (string)jsonobject["urn"];

            Response.Redirect("Viewer.html?token=" + authToken + "&urn=" + urn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are redirecting to view the model immediately after calling the translation, while you should have polled for the job status and wait for its completion.

Note that any translation job with our Model Derivative service is asynchronous and will be queued for processing right after they are called. Jobs with large models might take minutes and even hours to complete. See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-source-file-to-stl/#step-3-verify-the-job-is-complete) for API usage details to query the job status.

Also see below for sample .NET code to poll a web service: 
[Polling a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701054/polling-a-web-service)